# Pebble stopwatch change in font size bug

Tags: c, counter, stopwatch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I have been trying to get an app working on my pebble for a while now and I finally got it to work.  It's a sports counter that keeps track of the score for both teams and also has a built in stop watch in the middle.  Everything works as it should but if the stopwatch runs for 42 seconds then the font for the counters become very small.  I have no idea whats going on.

When I was looking around someone said it may be a memory leak, but this was not similar to my problem.

```
#include <pebble.h>

#define COUNTER_FONT_49 RESOURCE_ID_MACHINE_GUN_49
#define STOPWATCH_FONT_24 RESOURCE_ID_SPORTS_WORLD_24
#define HOME_AWAY_FONT_18 FONT_KEY_GOTHIC_18_BOLD

//---Counter Constants---
#define COUNTER_START 0
#define COUNTER_MAX 9999
#define COUNTER_MIN -9999
#define MAX_DIGITS 4

//---Interface Variables---
Window* window;
static Layer* layer;
static GFont counterFont;
static GFont stopwatchFont;
static TextLayer* teamAScore_layer;
static TextLayer* teamBScore_layer;
static TextLayer* big_time_layer;
static TextLayer* seconds_time_layer;
static TextLayer* home_away_layer;


//---Counter Variables---
char teamA_counter_text[MAX_DIGITS + 2 /* sign & \0 */];
char teamB_counter_text[MAX_DIGITS + 2 /* sign & \0 */];
int teamACounter;
int teamBCounter;
int singleClickIncrement;
int longClickIncrement;
int doubleClickIncrement;

//The Time
static double elapsed_time = 0;
static bool started = false;
static AppTimer* update_timer = NULL;
static double start_time = 0;
static double pause_time = 0;
time_t time_seconds();
void stop_stopwatch();
void start_stopwatch();
void handle_timer(void* data);
void update_stopwatch();

double float_time_ms() {
    time_t seconds;
    uint16_t milliseconds;
    time_ms(&seconds, &milliseconds);
    return (double)seconds + ((double)milliseconds / 1000.0);
}

void stop_stopwatch() {
    started = false;
    pause_time = float_time_ms();
    if(update_timer != NULL) {
        app_timer_cancel(update_timer);
        update_timer = NULL;
    }
}

void start_stopwatch() {
    started = true;
    if(start_time == 0) {
        start_time = float_time_ms();
    } else if(pause_time != 0) {
        double interval = float_time_ms() - pause_time;
        start_time += interval;
    }
    update_timer = app_timer_register(100, handle_timer, NULL);
}

void update_stopwatch() {
    static char big_time[] = "00:00";
    static char deciseconds_time[] = ".0";
    static char seconds_time[] = ":00";

    // Now convert to hours/minutes/seconds.
    int tenths = (int)(elapsed_time * 10) % 10;
    int seconds = (int)elapsed_time % 60;
    int minutes = (int)elapsed_time / 60 % 60;
    int hours = (int)elapsed_time / 3600;

    // We can't fit three digit hours, so stop timing here.
    if(hours > 99) {
        stop_stopwatch();
        return;
    }

    if(hours < 1) {
        snprintf(big_time, 6, "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        snprintf(deciseconds_time, 3, ".%d", tenths);
    } else {
        snprintf(big_time, 6, "%02d:%02d", hours, minutes);
        snprintf(seconds_time, 4, ":%02d", seconds);
    }

    // Now draw the strings.
    text_layer_set_text(big_time_layer, big_time);
    text_layer_set_text(seconds_time_layer, hours < 1 ? deciseconds_time : seconds_time);
}

void select_click_long_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, Window *window) {           //pressed SELECT LONG
    bool is_running = started;
    stop_stopwatch();
    start_time = 0;
    elapsed_time = 0;
    if(is_running) start_stopwatch();
    update_stopwatch();
}

static void select_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {         //pressed SELECT 
  if(started) {
        stop_stopwatch();
    } else {
        start_stopwatch();
    }
}

void handle_timer(void* data) {
    if(started) {
        double now = float_time_ms();
        elapsed_time = now - start_time;
        update_timer = app_timer_register(100, handle_timer, NULL);
    }
    update_stopwatch();
}

static int increment_value(int team_score, const int increment){
  if(team_score + increment <= COUNTER_MAX && team_score + increment >= COUNTER_MIN)
     team_score = team_score + increment;

  return team_score;
}

static void up_multi_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {       //pressed UP MULTI
  teamACounter = increment_value(teamACounter, doubleClickIncrement);
  layer_mark_dirty(layer);
}

static void up_click_long_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {        //pressed UP LONG
  teamACounter = increment_value(teamACounter, longClickIncrement);
  layer_mark_dirty(layer);
}

static void up_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {             //pressed UP 
  teamACounter = increment_value(teamACounter, singleClickIncrement);
  layer_mark_dirty(layer);
}

static void down_multi_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {     //pressed DOWN MULTI
  teamBCounter = increment_value(teamBCounter, doubleClickIncrement);
  layer_mark_dirty(layer);
}

static void down_click_long_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {     //pressed DOWN LONG
  teamBCounter = increment_value(teamBCounter, longClickIncrement);
  layer_mark_dirty(layer);
}

static void down_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {          //pressed DOWN
  teamBCounter = increment_value(teamBCounter, singleClickIncrement);
  layer_mark_dirty(layer);
}

static void click_config_provider(void *context) {
  window_single_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_SELECT, select_click_handler);
  window_long_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_SELECT, 700, (ClickHandler) select_click_long_handler, NULL);

  window_single_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_UP, up_click_handler);
  window_long_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_UP, 700, (ClickHandler)up_click_long_handler, NULL);
  window_multi_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_UP, 2, 10, 0, true, up_multi_click_handler);

  window_single_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_DOWN, down_click_handler);
  window_long_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_DOWN, 700, (ClickHandler)down_click_long_handler, NULL);
  window_multi_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_DOWN, 2, 10, 0, true, down_multi_click_handler);
}

static void update_layer(Layer *layer, GContext *ctx){
  GRect bounds = layer_get_frame(layer);
  counterFont = fonts_load_custom_font(resource_get_handle(COUNTER_FONT_49));

  graphics_context_set_text_color(ctx, GColorBlack);

  snprintf(teamA_counter_text, (MAX_DIGITS + 2)*sizeof(char), "%d", teamACounter);
  graphics_draw_text(ctx, 
                     teamA_counter_text, 
                     counterFont, 
                     GRect(0, 0, bounds.size.w - 10, 60),
                     GTextOverflowModeWordWrap, 
                     GTextAlignmentCenter, 
                     NULL);

  snprintf(teamB_counter_text, (MAX_DIGITS + 2)*sizeof(char), "%d", teamBCounter);
  graphics_draw_text(ctx, 
                     teamB_counter_text,
                     counterFont, 
                     GRect(0, 95, bounds.size.w - 10, 60), 
                     GTextOverflowModeWordWrap,
                     GTextAlignmentCenter, 
                     NULL);
}

static void window_load(Window *window) {
  // Get the root layer
  Layer *window_layer = window_get_root_layer(window);
  // Get the bounds of the window for sizing the text layer
  GRect bounds = layer_get_bounds(window_layer);

  layer = layer_create(bounds);
  layer_set_update_proc(layer, update_layer);
  layer_add_child(window_layer, layer);
}

static void window_unload(Window *window) {
  // Destroy TextLayer
  text_layer_destroy(teamAScore_layer);
  text_layer_destroy(teamBScore_layer);
  text_layer_destroy(big_time_layer);
  text_layer_destroy(seconds_time_layer);
}

void handle_init(void) {
  window = window_create();
  window_set_click_config_provider(window, click_config_provider);
  window_set_window_handlers(window, (WindowHandlers) {
      .load = window_load,
    .unload = window_unload,
  });

  //Set the counters start
  teamACounter = COUNTER_START;
  teamBCounter = COUNTER_START;
//---------------------------------------------TEMPERARY INCREMENT
  singleClickIncrement = 1;
  doubleClickIncrement = 2;
  longClickIncrement   = 3;

  Layer *root_layer = window_get_root_layer(window);
  stopwatchFont = fonts_load_custom_font(resource_get_handle(STOPWATCH_FONT_24));

  //-----Display Stop Watch-----
  big_time_layer = text_layer_create(GRect(0, 65, 86, 35));
  text_layer_set_text_alignment(big_time_layer, GTextAlignmentRight);
  text_layer_set_background_color(big_time_layer, GColorClear);
  text_layer_set_text(big_time_layer, "00:00");
  text_layer_set_font(big_time_layer, stopwatchFont);
  layer_add_child(root_layer, (Layer*)big_time_layer);

  seconds_time_layer = text_layer_create(GRect(86, 65, 49, 35));
  text_layer_set_text(seconds_time_layer, ".0");
  text_layer_set_background_color(seconds_time_layer, GColorClear);
  text_layer_set_font(seconds_time_layer, stopwatchFont);
  layer_add_child(root_layer, (Layer*)seconds_time_layer);

  //-----Display Home and Away-----
  home_away_layer = text_layer_create(GRect(124, 0, 20, 152));
  text_layer_set_text(home_away_layer, "\n H\n\n\n\n\n A");
  text_layer_set_background_color(home_away_layer, GColorBlack);
  text_layer_set_text_color(home_away_layer, GColorWhite);
  text_layer_set_font(home_away_layer, fonts_get_system_font(HOME_AWAY_FONT_18));
  layer_add_child(root_layer, (Layer*)home_away_layer);

  const bool animated = true;
  window_stack_push(window, animated);
}

void handle_deinit(void) {
  window_destroy(window);
}

int main(void) {
  handle_init();
  app_event_loop();
  handle_deinit();
}
```

Comment: Comments are key to investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading the custom font into memory each time the update_layer function is called. Eventually the app runs out of memory and can't load the font any more, which is why it uses the fallback (really small) font.

You should just load the custom font **once**, in your init function.